# $SO(3)$-invariant Lagrangian and null kinetic term for gauge fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, group-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

Let's say we have a Yang-Mills $SO(3)$ theory coupled to a real scalar field $\phi$. Then the Lagrangian can be written as

$$
{\cal L} = \frac{1}{2}(D_\mu \phi)^T D_\mu \phi + \mu^2 \phi^T \phi - \lambda (\phi^T \phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2}tr\left\{ A_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu\nu} \right\},\qquad D_\mu \phi = (\partial_\mu + iA_\mu^a T^a)\phi
$$
and
$$
A_{\mu\nu} = A_{\mu\nu}^a T^a
$$

In the case of $SO(3)$, its generators have zeros (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Lie_algebra) in the diagonal. Then,
$$
tr\left\{ A_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu\nu} \right\} = A_{\mu\nu}^a A^{b,\ \mu\nu} tr\{T^a T^b\} = 0
$$

This implies that for $SO(3)$, the kinectic Lagrangian for gauge fields is null, therefore the gauge fields have no propagator. Is this physically possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product of two matrices which have zeroes on the diagonal does not always have zeroes on the diagonal, so $\mathrm{tr}\{T^aT^b\} \neq 0$ for some $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 1):

As Emmy said, the trace in your lagrangian does **not** necessarily vanish. We can take for example
$$(T^a)_{jk} = -\varepsilon_{ajk}$$
for our generators which corresponds to the choice in the wikipedia article.
Then $$(T^aT^b)_{jk} = \varepsilon_{ajl}\varepsilon_{blk} = \delta_{ak}\delta_{jb} - \delta_{ab}\delta_{jk}$$
so that $$tr(T^aT^b) = - 2\delta_{ab} \neq 0 \, .$$